# Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Reader_HTML::listWorksheetNames()

Tags: php, iis, phpexcel

This is crazy. I need to process the excel file but it only runs well on xampp or wampsever, on IIS it almost does not work.
My code:

```
include_once "../excel/PHPExcel.php";
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
$listWorkSheets = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($file);
```

Error exporting:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   PHPExcel_Reader_HTML::listWorksheetNames()

Comment: Chances are good the include_once isn't working but without checking that it worked your code forges ahead blindly. Try using require or require_once and see if it dies because the require doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for help. But it not work when I change to require_once. .

Comment: The code works fine on wampserver and xampp but when I use IIS it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed 100% completed by add:

```
use PHPExcel_Settings;
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

After line code require "PHPExcel.php"